# Store Cell Value In Variable

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am trying to store the value of a cell in a variable using vba.  My code throws an error, what should I change so that the value of the cell is stored in my variable?

```
Dim total As Long
total = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).End.Value
Debug.Print (total)
```

The error I get is

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assigned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim total As Long
Dim wk as worksheet

Set wk = activesheet

total = wk.Range("D" & wk.Cells(wk.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row).value
Debug.Print (total)
```